# Как поочередно записать в файл списки и строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два списка и одна строка:

```py
l1 = ["g", "gg", "ggg"]
l2 = ["1", "11", "111"]
s1 = ("some text")
```

нужно записать в файл это все так чтобы получилось вот это:

```
g
some text
1
gg
some text
11
ggg
some text
111
```

Как это сделать ?

Comment: `with open(path, 'w') as f: for i in range(len(l1)): f.write(l1[i] + '\n'), f.write(s1 + '\n'), f.write(l2[i] + '\n')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l1 = ["g", "gg", "ggg"]
l2 = ["1", "11", "111"]
s1 = ("some text")

with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
    for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
        file.write("\n".join([a, s1, b]) + "\n")
```

Comment: на выходе будет вот это
g
1
some text
gg
11
some text
ggg
111
some text
а надо 
g
some text
1
gg
some text
11
ggg
some text
111

Comment: Так что уже не в состоянии сами поменять местами `b, s1`?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```py
l1 = ["g", "gg", "ggg"]
l2 = ["1", "11", "111"]
s1 = ("some text")

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(l1):
        f.write(l+"\n")
        f.write(s1+"\n")
        f.write(l2[i]+"\n")
```

Comment: line 6
for i, l in enumerate(l1):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: gsome text1ggsome text11gggsome text111 это в файле

Comment: @Pydeb Там просто переносы строк добавить надо. Поправил